# Adding ckeditor5 to Flask

Tags: flask, ckeditor

I take these from flask documentary. Ckeditor4 is coming when i set it, but i want ckeditor5.

https://flask-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic.html#initialization

```
         <form method="post">
                {{ ckeditor.load(pkg_type="basic") }}

                {{ ckeditor.load() }}

                {{ ckeditor.create() }}
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
```